# Rails associations of user/post/comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an app like a blog, with 3 models: user, post and comment. As expected, a comment belongs to both a user and a post.

I used the following associations:

User.rb

```
has_many :comments
has_many :posts
```

Post.rb

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

Comment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

And I tried to create comments using: 
@user.comments.create

However, this will relate the comment with user, but not with post. I want the comment to be associated wit BOTH user and post. Is there a way to do so? Or did I use the wrong associations?

I think it might be a bad practice to set the user_id or post_id by hand, so both ids are not in attr_accessible. I'm not sure if it is correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the `post_id`, specifically. Try `@user.comments.create(:post => @post)`.

Comment: This sounds like what you want - the polymorphic answer was for the wrong question...  And if you want to be able to set these attributes via a hash on creation, but protect them from modification by the user on update, take a look at attr_readonly: [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-attr_readonly).

Comment: When I tried: `@user.comments.create(:content => "hi", :post => @post)`, I got: `#<Comment id: nil, user_id: 1, post_id: nil, content: "hi", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`. The `@post` is `#<Post id: 4, title: "fooTitle", content: "fooContent", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-02-07 20:13:43", updated_at: "2011-02-07 20:13:43"`. It seems post-comment association was still missing. I'm not sure what went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Odd. I whipped up a test app with a bar User, Post, Comment set of classes. Through the console `user = User.create; post = Post.new; user.comments.create(:post => post)` yields `#<Comment id: 1, user_id: 1, post_id: 1, created_at: "2011-02-08 09:46:53", updated_at: "2011-02-08 09:46:53">`. Can you check what the comment is in your DB? Does it need a reload? Can you post exactly what you've done?

Comment: I checked the log, it says `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: post`. I guess it's because I only put `content` in `  attr_accessible :content`. Do I have to put `post_id` there to make the association? I was told it might not be good practice. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to set post_id to attr_accessible and set it manually to associate with current post. It works this way.

Comment: Cool. I haven't used `attr_accessible` myself, so I hadn't come across this problem. It looks like you should only need to do one of "put `post` in `attr_accessible`" and "assign `post` manually".

Answer (score 0):

If the comment needs to be associated with more than one model, we call it `polymorphic association`. You can have a look at `has_many_polymorphs` plug-in for that. I presume you are using rails 3, you can try the following:

You can have module defined in the `lib/commentable.rb` folder like this:

```
module Commentable
    def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
            has_many :comments, :as => commentable
        end
    end
end
```

In the Comment model you should say that it is polymorphic:

```
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

In both, Post and User models you can add the following:

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Since, in Rails 3 the lib folder is not loaded by default you should ask Rails to load that in your application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Now, Comment is polymorphic and any other model can be associated with it. This should do.

Comment: I think this means that a comment can be associated with only one of `User` and `Post` at once, which doesn't sound like the OP's intention.